# handle activity with segmented bar button

Tags: android, android-layout

I have create a segmented button in android , now i am bit confused about few things when a button loads. **I am using android 2.2**

I have 3 segmented button , and whenever a button is clicked i want to load and activity into it , 3 different activity for 3 different segmented button.

so i don;t know

1) how to handle or load activity with segmented button , or i need to switch to Tabbar for the same ?

2) Is it possible to slide the activity when the button is clicked ?

Here is the button that i have create

[image]

*Note: i don't want to use GreenDroid Library as that unnecessarily bulking up my app*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom button / "segmented control" looks a lot like the Holo-themed tabs.  I think you want a ViewPager as introduced in http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

Instead of 3 activities, you'll create 3 fragments, created using a `FragmentPagerAdapter`.  It will handle sliding for you when button is clicked (or if user swipes left/right.)

You'll want to pay particular attention to `FragmentTabsPager` found in http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabsPager.html and its associated layout file `fragment_tabs_pager.xml` in http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/res/layout/fragment_tabs_pager.html

Comment: sorry that i forget to mentioned that i am using Android 2.2 , does fragment work into that ?

Comment: Yes, using the Android Compatibility Libraries, which those samples I pointed out are using.  Instructions on how to download it and documentation for the Android Compatibility Library are located at http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html  That version supports API Level 4 and above, which includes Android 2.2 (API Level 8.)

Comment: Well i am not be alble to fetch the FragmentTabsPager running , do you have any example code ?

Comment: FragmentTabsPager is the example code.  What is the issue with running it?

Comment: Actually i have an activity which extends ListActivity now i don;t know how can i convert it into fragment

Comment: You can convert `ListActivity` into `ListFragment`.  ListFragment is documented at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html  I've used it extensively and it is a good replacement that plays well with the more modern Fragment-based infrastructure.

Comment: The problem is I got custom list view which has a listview and other buttons and all so i don't know where to put setContentView and findViewById and all

Comment: You can create your own custom `Fragment` subclass as well, then inflate/create your view in `onCreateView`.  Then do your `findViewById` work inside of `onActivityCreated`.

Comment: okay got the concept , but do you have your own example which shows the road map ?

Comment: Thanks for the help !! i figured it out :)